# Reading different types in C from File

Tags: c, scanf, c-strings

I'm trying to read in a file that has different types to read in (integers, chars). This is relatively simple, yet I'm confused on which method to use to read in these different values.

I'm using `fgets` to make sure the file isn't at the end, i.e;

```
char line[MAX_CHARS]; 
char ch;
FILE *infile = fopen("file.txt", "r"); 
const int MAX_CHARS = 50;

       while(fgets(line, MAX_CHARS, infile) != NULL)
```

Given the input;

> -Flight one
>
> 83, 34
>
> X XX  X
>
> X     X
>
> -Flight two
>
> ....

I want to print the line that starts with a dash, send the integers to a method, and then print the X's and spaces. So, my code for this would be:

```
if(line[0] == '-')
{
   printf("%s\n", line);
}

else if(2==sscanf(line, "%d%d", &long, &lat))
{
   coordinates(long, lat);
}
```

I used `scanf` to try to read the X's and spaces, but it doesn't work at all. `getchar()` doesn't seem to work either, so should I start over and instead read each `char` individually instead of a `char` array?

EDIT: So I did as someone suggested, this is my updated code to read in spaces and X's, but it is clearly not reading right, as it's not going to the next line of X's.

```
        else
        {
            while(line[++index] != '\0')
            {
                if(line[index]  == ' ')
                {
                  printf("%c", '.');
                }

                else if(line[index] == 'X')
                {
                  printf("%c", '*');

                }
            }
        }
```

For output;

> *Flight one
>
> .......*Flight two

Comment: Don't use long as variable name

Comment: @MohitJain I thought you meant "long ass variable names" and checked the edit history to see those long ass variables.

Comment: I think that for the second line you need to scan `"%d, %d"` instead of `"%d%d"`.

Comment: @barakmanos, Did as you suggested, I think that was an error in re-posting my code though. I think I'm having the most trouble with reading in the spaces and X's though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scanf(line, " %c", &ch)
/*           ^         */
```

The space before percent will cause `scanf` to ignore all whitespace characters (space, tab, newline) if present.

i.e. condition `if(ch == ' ')` will be always `false`.

In your question, this is not something that you like, so remove this whitespace.

**EDIT**
Also as suggested by [Barak Manos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017867/reading-different-types-in-c-from-file#comment50061657_31017867)

> I think that for the second line you need to scan `"%d, %d"` instead of `"%d%d"`.

Comment: Okay, I did, but am on the right path to even use `scan(line, "%c", %ch)`, or should I use a different method? I deleted the whitespace, but I think that the code is expecting the user to put in characters, which is not what I want at all

Comment: Why not simply use `line[0]` or generally `line[index]`?

Comment: Doesn't `line[0]` only read the first character, that's why it worked for reading the `-`, but I want to read all the characters in the line. I was considering of doing an `index` and then increment it while checking each value in `line`

Comment: Yes this looks good: `int index = -1; while(line[++index] != '\0') {...}`

Comment: I added an update to show my new code and the input and output, respectively.

Comment: @kris [Check here](http://ideone.com/Lk8lVi). I copied your code to ideone and it gives required output.